# Is there any way to get Android Management API device id from app

Tags: android, android-management-api

I'm trying to develop Android Management API + kiosk app.

I want to get the device id(`enterprises/xxxxx/devices/xxxxx`) from the kiosk app.
My purpose is to associate the device id with the kiosk app id created in app.

Can I get the device id from the kiosk app? Is there any other solution?

Comment: I'm not sure you can fetch the `device id` directly from your Kiosk app. But you could create a Managed Configuration for you Kiosk app, then push the `device id` through it.

Comment: I would also recommend using managed configurations, I added a more detailed answer below to explain it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible for your app to directly access the device ID.

However you can achieve a similar result by [exposing a managed configuration](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations) in your app with one string and configuring it in the [`ApplicationPolicy`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#applicationpolicy) with a different policy for each device. The managed configuration can contain a string property that you set to the device ID for each device.

The managed configuration file in your app would look like:

```
<restrictions xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <restriction
    android:key="deviceId"
    android:title="ID of the device"
    android:restrictionType="string" />

</restrictions>
```

And the policy would look like:

```
{
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.example",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "managedConfiguration": {
        "deviceId": "1a2b3c4d5e6f"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In addition, to set the policy as soon as a new device is enrolled you can [set up Pub/Sub notifications](https://developers.google.com/android/management/notifications) and listen for `ENROLLMENT` events, the `data` field of the notification contains a `Device` resource with the device ID, therefore allowing you to create a new policy and assign it to the device.

Comment: While this approach works, it's a bit cumbersome. Is there any way to use Android Management API and have a custom developed app with permission to retrieve more information about the device, enterprise etc from the DPC?

Comment: @Hameno Did you find out if it is possible to retrieve the extra information (e.g. device, enterprise) from the Android app?

Comment: Do you guys able to get the details form the android app?

Comment: This is very limiting, isn't it? If a certain policy-change should be applied to `X` devices, then `X` policies should be patched (rather than just 1).
**Is there a way to get around that?**

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex. It is very basic thing that we need. If I need to remove policy from one user how will I know that users device. There should be an easy way management api team.

Comment: Was this ever addressed? Is it possible to obtain a managed device's unique Id after enrollment?