# Android management API: find device in list of devices on android Q

Tags: android, android-management-api, cosu

We have a cosu app, that can manage its lock state with calls to Android management API. To do this, we receive a list of devices with `devices.list` query, compare each device's `hardwareInfo.serialNumber` with IMEI, received from `Build.getSerial()` and then use the following code to apply different policy:

```
  fun patchDevice(device: Device, policyName: String) {
    device.policyName = policyName
    androidManagementClient.enterprises().devices().patch(device.name, device).execute()
 }
```

However, according to docs, hardware device identifiers are no longer available in android Q. ([link](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/data-identifiers#device-ids)) Right now, we use devices with Android 8, but I suspect our code will break on newer OS. So, the questions are:

1. Is there any other way to identify the device in the list, without knowing its hardware ids?
2. Or maybe there is a way to guarantee that using READ_PHONE_STATE will still provide us with IMEI on Android Q? In the documentation it is stated that *If your app is the device or profile owner app, you need only the READ_PHONE_STATE permission to access non-resettable device identifiers, even if your app targets Android Q.* However, AMAPI has its own device owner app, so I'm not sure if that will work in our case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach here is to pass the device `name` to your COSU app via a managed configuration. You COSU app can then call the API using that name. With this approach you don't need to access the serial number of the device.

This approach is explained in details in [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236596/is-there-any-way-to-get-android-management-api-device-id-from-app/55251103#55251103).

Comment: I wouldn't call this approach simple, but that's a solution anyway, thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to expose the ANDROID_ID in the Device object? The solution you provided works but it gets extremely cumbersome when you have more than 1000 devices. Thanks!

Comment: The ANDROID_ID is the last part of the device's `name`: `enterprises/LC01234567/devices/<ANDROID_ID>`