# How to get Device id for using Android Management API?

Tags: android, mdm, android-management-api

I'm trying to build an app for MDM using Android Management API.
But I can't find an API to create a device id.
How to get Device id for using Android Management API?

Comment: Do you want to create an id or get the one from Android?

Comment: @heX  I want to create an id when an app launches.

Comment: You want to create an id and show it in the management api device payload?

Comment: @heX Yes. i want to send it to android mgmt api parameter.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices

You can add any number of `systemProperties` you want. However, the difficult part is knowing your Android Management Device name. Until Android 9, you can cross reference between the management data and your app using the serial number. After android 9, there's no easy way to cross reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236596/is-there-any-way-to-get-android-management-api-device-id-from-app/55251103#55251103

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to get Android Management API device id from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236596/is-there-any-way-to-get-android-management-api-device-id-from-app)

Comment: I misunderstood Android mgmt API guide. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deviceId` is generated upon successful enrollment. You can list the devices using [Devices.list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/list) after enrollment. The deviceId is stored in the `name` field in the form `enterprises/{enterpriseId}/devices/{deviceId}` you can check the [Device](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices) resource for more info.

Comment: is it possible to get this information from the Android app side?

Comment: You need to have special permissions to do this. You can check this link for more info. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids