# Is there anyway to reapply same Policy to Same Device?

Tags: android-management-api

For Example, Policy A is updated and linked with the device.
But Policy A is not applied properly in the Device because of user intervention.

I want to Re-apply the Policy to the Device again. Is there any way to apply the policy to the device again?.

note:

1. I tried [Device.patch](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/patch). But it does not reapply policy in Device.
   Nothing occurs in the Device. Because already same policy applies to the device.
2. With Updating Policy. we can reflect the updated policy in the Device. But there is no change in Policy,
   if I try [Policies.patch](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies/patch), Policy Object Will not get updated (Version Not change).
   SO Policy is not reflecting in the Device.
   could not able to update the policy without any changes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236596/is-there-any-way-to-get-android-management-api-device-id-from-app

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to apply the same policy on the same device without updating the policy. Also, a device can only have a single policy at any given time. Please refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-policy#apply_a_policy_to_devices) for applying policy to a device.

However, if it is necessary to re-apply a policy since the initial policy was not applied due to user interference, I suggest that you add a policy that will not directly affect your device. With this, the policy will be updated and can be applied to the device.